# How to open results in excel when clicked on a link from web page created using perl cgi script

Tags: excel, perl, cgi

I have a Perl CGI script that displays results (50 rows) from a database query on a web page.

At the end of each row, I have a column which is HTML href link.

When this link is clicked, I have to open that particular record in Excel and allow it to be saved.

I tried using `SpreadSheet::WriteExcel`, but no luck.

Can anyone please give me a help link or help thread regarding this?

Code:

```
while(my $row = $query->fetchrow_hashref){
    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{promoter}</td>";
    $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{company}</td>";
    $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{bunit}</td>";
    $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{sub}</td>";
    $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{region}</td>";
    $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{workstream}</td>";
    $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{contractor}</td>";
    $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{amp}</td>";
    ### Link to open this record in excel sheet ##
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already?  All you've shown is a sample of the HTML table, not the code you tried to generate/download the excel file.  
The basic flow would be   

1:  Gather the data
2:  Generate the excel file
3:  Send the headers for an excel file
4:  Send the content of the excel file

Comment: I did not know where to start. Indirectly you are asking me the question i asked first.

Comment: How can one ask specific question when working on something new.
All i was asking was any similar threads or any links that will help.

Anyways, i managed to do it. will post the answer here shortly.

Comment: You said you tried SpreadSheet::WriteExcel.  What did you try and and why did you say it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In the main script, create a link with anchor tag which redirects to new script where you define what exactly need to be written in Excel.

Created a new script where below sub routine is defined.

When the link is clicked, it will ask for Download/Save option for excel document.

Code:1

```
                            $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{workstream}</td>";
                            $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{contractor}</td>";
                            $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC' nowrap>$row->{amp}</td>";
                            $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC'><a href='notC.cgi?promoter=$row->{promoter}' target='_blank'>Link</a></td>";
                            $html .= "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC'><a href='escC.cgi?promoter=$row->{promoter}' target='_blank'>Link</a></td>";
```

Code:2

```
sub doExcel {

print "Content-type: excel/ms-excel; name=notC.xls\n";
print "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=notC.xls\n\n";
binmode(STDOUT);

    my $dbh = Kearynet::Database->Handle();
    my $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM projects.notNames where notPromoter = '$notPromoter' ");
    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetchrow_hashref){
            $searchresults{ $row->{notId} } = $row;
    }

    my $fname="notContacts_".$notPromoter.".xls";

    print "Content-type: excel/ms-excel; name=$fname\n";
    print "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$fname\n\n";
    binmode(STDOUT);

    my $x=0;
    my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new(\*STDOUT);
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet("NotificationContacts");
    $worksheet->activate();
    $worksheet->write($x, 0,  "Not RouteId");
    $worksheet->write($x, 1,  "Not Promoter");
    $worksheet->write($x, 2,  "Not Level");
    .....
            foreach my $r (sort keys %searchresults){
            my $nrow = $searchresults{$r};
            if( not $row->{notId} ){
                    $worksheet->write($x, 0,  $nrow->{notRouteId} );
                    $worksheet->write($x, 1,  $nrow->{notPromoter} );
                    $worksheet->write($x, 2,  $nrow->{notLevel} );
                    $worksheet->write($x, 3,  $nrow->{notRegion} );
                    $worksheet->write($x, 4,  $nrow->{nTWRConId_1} );
                    $worksheet->write($x, 5,  $nrow->{nTWRConName_1} );
            }
        }

    }
```